# How to create a struct parameter that is a closure with input, returning `some View` instead of `AnyView` in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, parameters, swiftui, closures, return-type

**Current situation:**

I'm trying to create a reusable view in SwiftUI that returns another view passed into it. At the moment I'm using a closure that returns `AnyView`, as the parameter.
When I initialize the reusable view I pass on a custom view wrapped inside `AnyView()`.

**Goal:**

Ideally I'd like a way to omit the `AnyView()` wrapper and just pass on my `CustomViewA` or `CustomViewB` as is.

**My attempts and issues:**

I tried changing the closure parameter to return `some View` but I'm getting the following error:

> 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions

I've seen a few attempts on S.O. to work around that by somehow using a generic parameter but I'm not sure how to implement this in my case or if it's even possible. Also important to note, the closure needs to take a String as its own input parameter.

**Example code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReusableView: View {
    let outputView: (String) -> AnyView
    
    var body: some View {
        outputView("Hello World")
    }
}

struct CustomViewA: View {
    let label: String
    
    init(_ label: String) {
        self.label = label
    }
    var body: some View {
        return Text(label)
    }
}

struct CustomViewB: View {
    let label: String
    
    init(_ label: String) {
        self.label = label
    }
    var body: some View {
        return HStack{
            Text(label)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReusableView() {
            AnyView(CustomViewA($0))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make `ReusableView` generic and declare the return type of your closure as the generic type.

```
struct ReusableView<Output: View>: View {
    let outputView: (String) -> Output
    
    var body: some View {
        outputView("Hello World")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReusableView() {
            CustomViewA($0)
        }
    }
}
```